# WINAPI, what is a device context and when do i have to release, delete or ignore it?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I know how to use them for extremely simple tasks like retrieve it by the BeginPaint function and release it with EndPaint once i've done the painting, i'm able to select objects into them, but i want to understand them more. Could you please explain the rules i should follow when i work with them and explain why? For example when i select a brush into a device context, should i delete it? When i retrieve a handle to a device context, does the OS releases it at the end of the program without problems or i should manually do it?

Comment: That's actually a big topic, worthy of several chapters in a book.  Fortunately, Charles Petzold has written that book, called **Programming Windows**.

Comment: Actually, the MSDN website does a pretty job at this -- they tend to tell you what to do for cleanup. As an example, the page describing the BeginPaint() also tells you to call EndPaint() when you're done. On the other hand, the page about GetStockObject() only tells you "It is not necessary (but it is not harmful) to delete stock objects by calling DeleteObject.". This is always a per-case thing -- but pages that "create" something for you to use generally tell you how to clean it up.

Comment: [Device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts) is a fine introduction.